# contact control panel unable to install in salesforce

Tags: node.js, salesforce, ivr, amazon-connect, call-recording

## Amazon Connect CTI Adapter in Salesforce App Exchange unable to install in salesforce

## this app can't be installed.
there are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
wrong type for the attribute

[Click Here To Check the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCOZ0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into the setting in SFDC and check the “omni-channel” box

1.From Setup, enter Omni-Channel Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Omni-Channel Settings.
2.Select Enable Omni-Channel.
3.Click Save.